# Java Regular expression does not match using Apache RE

Tags: java, regex, apache

I have this regular expression string:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\t\s\n\r!$()*,-./:;=?@`][{}_~|]+$
```

This RE should return true for the following:

```
!$()*,-./:;=?@`][{}_~|
```

I'm using RE of Apache and get false when running match function.
I think my regular expression is missing something, maybe handling with special characters.
 
The question is, what is wrong with my expression?
 here is my RE matching function:

```
public static String runRegularExpression(String string, String regularExpression, int parenthesis)
{
    String result = null;

    try
    {
        RE reCmd = new RE(regularExpression);

        if (reCmd.match(string))
        {
            result = reCmd.getParen(parenthesis);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception re)
    {
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: escape all the backslashes one more time.

Comment: I need to escape the RE string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You regex must not have unescaped hyphen in the middle of character class.
2. If you already have `\s` then there is no need to match `\n` and `\t` since `\s` matches all white-spaces that includes space, tab and newlines.
3. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be shortened to `\w`
4. Backslashes need to be double escaped.

Try this regex:

```
^[\\w\\s\\r!$()*,./:;=?@`{}\\[\\]~|-]+$
```

Comment: match input: !$()*,-./:;=?@`][{}_~|

Comment: doesn't match input: i ╣glε╧m♂▬!,♠•

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why it is so frustrating.. :)

Comment: I think I found the problem. I removed the character \ in my input and it worked. Maybe I need to escape it somehow...

Comment: Sorry not this \ but this /

Comment: FYI, the second input with special characters was needed to be escaped in order for the match function to work.